# Globally replace template

Tags: template, catalog, default

I'm trying to globally replace the `catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` and the `catalog/category/view.phtml` templates using local.xml. I know I could just put my versions of the file with the same name in my theme folder, but I read that's not best practice.

I thought to change it globally, in my `<default>` tags, I could place:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/list/tia_toolbar.phtml</template></action>
</reference>

<reference name="category.products">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/tia_view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

But that doesn't work, yet it does when I place it in `<catalog_category_default>` and `<catalog_category_layered>` tags, but I'd rather not repeat the same bit of code across all the different category layouts.

Why doesn't it work in my `<default>` tags and is there anyway to make it work?

Comment: Default tag is used to contain common directives for all instances. Other tags specify these directives and have higher priority over default. Use Netbeans, for example, to find all your templates references in *.xml files and redefine them in your local.xml

Comment: I do want to replace all instances rather than redefine each one, but I understand what your saying. The other tags have a higher priority. Is there a way to specify priority? Kinda like !important in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options to follow:
1) Redefine each reference from xml files in your local.xml
2) Create new theme/Use your theme and create the same files under the same directories. For example:

```
<default package>/<default theme>/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
<your package>/<your theme>/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
```

You have 1 more option like
3) Extend certain classes and define templates in __construct method here (It's easy, but wrong way to do it. And very uncomfortable for those who will work with this further.)
It's better to use 1 from the 2 above.